# How to add a character to the beginning of a line and end of a line in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a data set I get from my IT group. They have an automated extract they are unwilling to change.

The files looks like this (add more lines as requested)

col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4

data1#|#data2#|#data3#|#data4

data1#|#data2#|#data3#|#data4

cdata1#|#da#ta2#|#data3#|#data4

(line 4, this is an example where a # in my data screws up the quote character of only #)

The # look like they are attempting to be quote characters. I'd like to use them like that, but for whatever reason they don't include one at the start of each line or the end of each line. The files are of various column counts, so I'm trying to process them to basically add a # to the start and end of each line.

Also since # is often found in my data I'd like to convert the # into ### to make the import to my tool cleaner.

So I'd like

###col1###|###col2###|###col3###|###col4###|###col4###

How could I accomplish this?

## current code being used to process csv:

```
csv_pointer = open(file, encoding=CSV_Encoding, errors=Error_Detection)
csv_reader = csv.reader(
    csv_pointer,
    delimiter=CSV_Seperator,
    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

)
batch = list()
# for each row in csv reader
for row in csv_reader:
    # append the processed row to the batch list
    # processed row meaning we strip down the fields to remove redundant 
data
    # and add Nones if the length of the row is not up to the FIELDS_COUNT
    batch.append([k.strip() for k in row] + [None] * (FIELDS_COUNT - len(row)))
# check if the batch length is greater than ROWS_AT_ONCE
if len(batch) >= ROWS_AT_ONCE:
    # if it is use the executemany over the cursor to insert the data in the batch list to the database
    curr.executemany(insert_func(Table_Name), batch)
    # commit
    conn.commit()
    # set the batch to empty list again
    batch = list()
# if the batch list is not empty
if batch:
# if it is use the executemany over the cursor to insert the data in the batch list to the database
curr.executemany(insert_func(Table_Name), batch)
# commit
conn.commit()
# delete batch (just incase the program message up and it need to delete the batch)
del batch
```

I attempted to change my delimiter to #|#, which seems like it would fix my problem, but it's returning the error:
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Comment: its a pipe delimited csv? also can you provide some rows where you mention `#` is found in the data besides the header?

Comment: I added some example data to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may, why not use the delimiting strategy of the csv format from your IT team?
You can split on "#|#" in parsing tool (if it's in python):

```py
text="col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4"
values = text.split("#|#")
# values is ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

Using the csv module, you'll have to specify the `quoting` parameter. Specifically on line 2:

```py
csv_reader = csv.reader(
    csv_pointer,
    delimiter=CSV_Seperator,
    quoting='#'
)
```

If that interferes with `'#'`s in your fields, then you may want to take a literal approach to this problem (without the csv library):

```py
batch = []
with open(file, r) as f:
     for l in f.readlines()[1:]: # if there's a header, if not, then remove the [1:]
         batch.append(l.split("#|#"))
```

Comment: because I'm an idiot!!!! thanks! this makes a lot of sense.

I get this error: TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Comment: TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you loading this from a csv? Can you post the line of code that is giving the error?

Comment: Yes, I'm loading from a csv. I posted the code. Basically it appears the csv module only allows one character as a delimiter, any way around this?

Comment: @David54321 Updated with specific context from your code: TLDR, use the quoting param. If this messes with '#' inside your data let me know.

Comment: yeah so I went with the literal approach because separating on #|# seems like it was the intent of IT. When I just used '#' as the quote it reset my quote characters to have a # in the data, which is not what I want.

Comment: @David54321A side note, it seems pretty shortsighted for the data be quoted with '#' when '#' occurs naturally in the data. You should definitely track down the person in charge of this decision.(If only if '#' was meant to be a quoting character)

Comment: The data I have has several open text fields the end user can put anything in and the data is several millions of rows long. So it's a struggle to find any character that's not used. I even typically have a dozen or so rows with a new line character that ends up messing up those lines. I'm not really sure if there's a perfect single character that can be used. I think the pattern of #|# is unique enough where it's probably a good solution since the pattern probably never exists naturally in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
#Initial text
text="col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4"
#adds a ### to start and end
text='###{}###'.format(text)
#Replaces #|# with ###|### 
text=text.replace("#|#","###|###")
```

This returns:

```
###col1###|###col2###|###col3###|###col4###
```

Obviously, this would need to go in a loop of some kind to go through all the data you have, and could also be consolidated into one line but I split it up to try and make it clearer.

Comment: I think the general `text.replace` would replace naturally-occuring `#`s in his data. Not sure if this is ok.

Comment: If that's the case you can be stricter and do `text.replace("#|#", "###|###")`, then you'd also need to change `text='#{}#'.format(text)` to `text='###{}###'.format(text)`

Comment: I think that's a fine edit to make to your answer-- I'm not OP.